# Is it possible to disable ldap passwords for a user without disabling their account?

Tags: linux, ldap, passwd

We have a cluster that uses an internal LDAP domain for user authentication that previously used passwords stored in LDAP.  We have now moved the login machine to use krb5 for password authentication against an external kdc.  We would like to remove the local LDAP passwords if we can.  Is there an equivalent in ldap to the traditional unix auth command `usermod -p '!' user`?

Comment: What LDAP server are you using? Not all of them work the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For OpenLDAP, **remove the `userPassword` attribute** from each user account.

Unfortunately there are no standard commands for managing LDAP user accounts, so you'll need `ldapsearch | awk/sed/grep | ldapmodify` or script the batch update using Perl/Python.

**Alternatively:** Instead of disabling LDAP password auth entirely, you **can** have the LDAP server validate the bind passwords against Kerberos. Of course, this is not as good as actual Kerberos authentication (SASL GSSAPI), but it may be useful if you still have software that relies on LDAP 'simple bind'.

Changing each user's `userPassword` attribute to `{SASL}user@REALM` (containing their Kerberos principal) will make OpenLDAP perform pass-through password validation using the 'saslauthd' daemon (from Cyrus SASL). Configure it to be launched as `saslauthd -a krb5` and it will verify the passwords against your Kerberos KDC.

Note that saslauthd *requires* the system to have a 'host/' principal in its machine keytab (/etc/krb5.keytab).

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!